# Finding an approximate Git fork-point

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, fuzzy-comparison

Often when vendors publish their kernels, they either release a tarball or squash all the commits down into one (branch `public` in this post); I have no access to `internal`. I'm attempting to create a branch (`recovery`) to clearly identify what changes have been made from the mainline kernel (`original`).

```
original: A--B--C--D--E--F
internal: A--B--C--D
                    \
                     G--I--J
public:   J
```

Because `public` does not contain `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D`, using `git merge-base --fork-point` will not identify any exact matches with `original`. Ideally, I'm looking to identify the commit in `original` that has the least amount of different lines (or files) with `public` (which will likely be `D`). Once I identify that `D` is the most similar to `J`, I can create `recovery`.

```
recovery: A--B--C--D--J
```

I could rebase `public` onto `original`'s `HEAD`, but then I would end up with `E` and `F` in my history. This adds a far amount of noise with large repositories, and also makes it appears as if those changes were reverted in `J` (when in reality they never existed on `internal`).

```
attempt:  A--B--C--D--E--F--J
```

Comment: In other words, you're looking among the commits (A,B,C,D,E,F) for the one that has the least amount of differences compared to J?

Comment: Exactly, that's the goal.

Answer (score 0):

The following script should do the trick. It finds all the commits in a given range, and then estimates the number of different lines between each of them and the reference commit, and finds the minimal difference.

```
#!/bin/bash

commit_to_compare_with=d67e
commit_range=1cb1d..e172

list_of_commits=($(git rev-list $commit_range))
num_of_commits=${#list_of_commits[@]}
minimal_diff_count=100000000

echo
echo Found $num_of_commits commits in the range $commit_range
echo

count_lines_of_diff() { git diff $1 $2 | wc -l; }

for c in "${list_of_commits[@]}"
do
  diff_count=$(count_lines_of_diff $commit_to_compare_with $c)
  echo ${c:0:4} differs from ${commit_to_compare_with:0:4} by $diff_count lines
  if [ $diff_count -lt $minimal_diff_count ]
  then
    most_similar_commit=$c
    minimal_diff_count=$diff_count
  fi
done

echo
echo Most similar commit to $commit_to_compare_with is $most_similar_commit
```

Here's the output I'm getting:

```
Found 5 commits in the range 1cb1d..e172

e172 differs from d67e by 45 lines
1431 differs from d67e by 26 lines
20e2 differs from d67e by 347 lines
fb80 differs from d67e by 347 lines
8d67 differs from d67e by 360 lines

Most similar commit to d67e is 14310bc0cf69967d4781e0aec2fd2cca21d72ac6
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [gitxref](https://github.com/ali1234/gitxref) can do this, which was written for the exact same use-case (vendor tarballs with history stripped out).